# How to port forward using python

Tags: python, linux, ssh, portforwarding, openssh

I have a remote server containing a database whose address is private. When i run the script i get

`server connected`

`Connection Failed`

```
import psycopg2
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import os

try:
    with SSHTunnelForwarder(
         ('Remote_server_ip', Remote_server_port),
         ssh_private_key="/home/User/.ssh/id_rsa",
         ssh_username="xxxxx",
         remote_bind_address=(Database_private_ip, Database_private_port)) as server:

         server.start()
         print ("server connected")

         params = {
             'database': 'xxxxx',
             'user': 'xxxxx',
             'password': 'xxxxxx',
             'host': 'localhost',
             'port': PORT
             }

         conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
         curs = conn.cursor()
         print ("database connected")

except:
    print ("Connection Failed")
```

I'm thinking port forwarding is still not being executed so that i can be able to access the db thus why i don't get `database connected`

How do i solve this?

Comment: first of all, catch an exception which is being thrown (in an `except` block) and find out where is the failure point

Comment: @drompix I'm getting an error, can't connect to database. Note that i use same credentials to access db after i manually do the port forwarding and it always work. Any idea how to fix that in this script?